# AngularJS UI Bootstrap rating control

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to bind directive's attribute to a scope variable. I would like my UI Bootstrap control to dynamically change appearance when this scope variable changes value.

Here is the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gEjerpXhy3IuT5qRNeL8?p=preview

Every time you press on some of the checkmarks, $scope.max is increased by 1. 
But, since that same $scope.max is passed to the 'rating' element as the 'max' attribute, I would like this 'rating' element to put additional checkmark on the right every time I click on some of the existing checkmarks.

I guess I am trying to re-draw this 'rating' element with new parameters. Is this possible and how?

Comment: are you trying to change the number of checkmarks with every click? this will be very confusing for users.

Comment: My exact use case would only discourage other SO users from helping me. This is just an esence of my problem...
I would like to have multiple rating elements like this. Then have fixed amount of point to distribute across multiple ratings.
So when one rating is decreased from 7 to 4, all other rating element now have an extra 3 points available. When one of the rating  uses up these 3 points, then all of them don't have any extra points available...

Comment: in the contrary - the more you depict the issue, the easier it is to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to simulate the behavior you want by adding an ng-if to the element, and modifying a boolean value when the rating changes.
`<rating ng-if="render" value="rating.x" max="rating.max"`...

```
    $scope.rating.max += 1;        
    $scope.render = false;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.render = true;  
    }, 0, true);
```

[Here is a demo](http://plnkr.co/JQXQ58AV4yKb3moqDBPt), forked from your original plunkr.

For what it is worth, I think you would be better off customizing the [directive's source](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/rating/rating.js) or just writing your own.  This workaround isn't going to scale, and it wouldn't be too hard to sprinkle in the functionality you need.